# Why combining pipeline operator with ceiling function doesn't work in R?

Tags: r, pipeline, ceil

When I try to use `ceiling()` function, it works okay, but when I try to divide something and give it to the ceiling function using pipeline operator `(2/10 %>% ceiling())`, I get a problem.

```
ceiling(0.2)
1

ceiling(2/10)
1

2/10
0.2

2/10 %>% ceiling()
0.2

2 %>% `/`(10)
0.2

2 %>% `/`(10) %>% ceiling()
1

0.2 %>% ceiling()
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `2/10 %>% ceiling()` works as `2/(10 %>% ceiling())`, i.e. `%>%` has precedence over `/`.

Put differently, `2/10 %>% ceiling()` = `2/10` = `0.2`

Answer (score 1):

One `magrittr` solution could be:

```
2 %>%
 divide_by(10) %>%
 ceiling()

[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of operator precedence.

You can clarify what you want to do by using round or curly brackets

```
library(magrittr)
(2/10) %>% ceiling()

{2/10} %>% ceiling()
```